# How to access a NodeJS exception text programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

The exception object in NodeJS has an unusual structure. I'd like to be able to access the error message, but it's not a named attribute of the object. For example:

```
var fs = require("fs");

function main() {
   "use strict";

   try {
      var stats = fs.statSync("./nonexistantFile.txt");
      console.log(stats);
   }
   catch (exception) {
      console.error("exception: " + JSON.stringify(exception));
      console.log(exception);
   }
};

main();
```

This code prints the following output:

```
exception: {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"./nonexistantFile.txt"}
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './nonexistantFile.txt']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: './nonexistantFile.txt' }
```

You can see that `console.log()` is printing an error text message in a way that makes it appear to be part of the object. Is that text part of the exception object? Or is it something that `console.log()` is adding?

I would like to be able to capture the error text message and store it. How do I access that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `exception.message`.

More information can be found here: [Error at MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)